# Cannot delete GDI+ Image

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, gdi+, delete-operator

I am programming a basic image converter to convert an image to a BMP. I clear up the Image at the end to avoid memory leaks. However, when I try to compile it, this error comes up:

> type 'class Gdiplus::Image' argument given to 'delete', expected pointer

I have checked multiple websites but when I use their examples, it still comes up with that compiler error. Even Microsoft's examples come up with that error! I saw a website containing a way to delete the Image but I can't remember the link or the way that they deleted the Image.

My code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

using namespace Gdiplus;

int GetEncoderClsid(const WCHAR* format, CLSID* pClsid)
{
    using namespace Gdiplus;    UINT  num = 0;          // number of image encoders
    UINT  size = 0;         // size of the image encoder array in bytes

    ImageCodecInfo* pImageCodecInfo = NULL;

    GetImageEncodersSize(&num, &size);
    if(size == 0)
        return -1;  // Failure

    pImageCodecInfo = (ImageCodecInfo*)(malloc(size));
    if(pImageCodecInfo == NULL)
    return -1;  // Failure

    GetImageEncoders(num, size, pImageCodecInfo);

    for(UINT j = 0; j < num; ++j)
    {
        if( wcscmp(pImageCodecInfo[j].MimeType, format) == 0 )
        {
            *pClsid = pImageCodecInfo[j].Clsid;
            free(pImageCodecInfo);
            return j;  // Success
        }
    }

    free(pImageCodecInfo);
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    CLSID bmpClsid;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
    Image picture(L"TEST.GIF");
    GetEncoderClsid(L"image/bmp", &bmpClsid);
    picture.Save(L"Mosaic2.bmp", &bmpClsid, NULL);
    delete picture;
    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    return 0;
}
```

I will put you in the credits of the program if you give me an answer that works.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `delete` only works on pointers and your "picture" is an object (unless it is overloaded in some way). Moreover, since it's a local object it should call destructor at the end of main (which should release related memory, including loaded image). But in case memory needs to be released before `GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);` you can adapt your code to use pointers:

```
Image *picture = new Image (L"TEST.GIF");
GetEncoderClsid(L"image/bmp", &bmpClsid);
picture->Save(L"Mosaic2.bmp", &bmpClsid, NULL);
delete picture;
```

Comment: This code worked faster than my old code! I will DEFINETLY add your name to the credits.